# Activate Mobile Device With Out Sim Card

Tags: iphone, device

I brought iPhone 5c and upgraded to IOS 8, by mistake rest the mobile device.  Now its ask for sim to insert for activation. 
Without sim card how to activate mobile device IPhone5C?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could actually use a GPP sim card, what it does is that it piggy backs on to a carrier. You can find them at amazon or ebay retailers